# google fcm cannot receive notification when app is killed

Tags: android

I made a app integrated Google FCM, but when the application was killed can not receive push notification message, I was tested using Samsung phone .

Answer (score 0):

Try to register receiver in mainfest file rather than declare in activity.

Or don't unregister your register if you register it in activity.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqBdD.png

FCM no receive only two service, configured in manifest